# How to get the value from method in Visual Basic 6

Tags: vb6

The code below returns error after the return statement

```
Private Sub Command1_Click()
  Dim str As String
  str = display("test")
  MsgBox (str)
End Sub

Public Function display(s As String) As String
  s = "updated"
  Return s
End Function
```

Any ideas why?

Comment: Is this VB.Net or VB6? I'm confused as it says Vb6 in the title but is tagged as Vb.Net, where does .Net come into this? Also, what error? It would be helpful if we knew.

Comment: @Binary Worrier, I think, he was trying to convert VB.NET code to VB6.

Comment: @hgulyan: Now THAT makes sense, had a Homer moment there, couldn't see what was going on . . .

Comment: @Binary Worrier, I'm used to answer low rep users' answers, trying to figure out what they mean, before they make it more clear.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change display function. The difference is that in vb6 functions return a value not with *return*, but with it's name(in this case *display*), like below.

```
   Public Function display(s As String) As String 
       s = "updated" 
       display = s 
   End Function
```